# Some spaceline questions

Tags: spacemacs, mode-line

So, I'm trying out spaceline, I have a few problems I can't figure out.

1. My segments does not display correctly, there is a weird display conflict that look like small boxes between each segment, is this a bug or can it be fixed?

   [image]
2. I don't know what is the "Mod" next to "Git:master". How do I get rid of this? I tried switching off most of the segments, does not seem to have any effect on the "Mod".
3. I want to force spaceline to always show buffer-position and hud. When I navigate blocks of text, I'll sometimes see the hud and buffer-position, but mostly I see "ALL" or "END".
4. Is there a way to change the highlight color in the modeline from orange to custom color?

Regards.

**Update 01:**

The "MOD" at the end of "Git:master" is controlled by the version-control variable, I think it indicates a modification on current branch.

Is there no way to turn that off?

Comment: Regarding item 1, in case you're on OSX: those "boxes" are not show if you use YAMAMOTO's Emacs Mac port. It can be installed using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh/) by executing `brew install emacs-mac` (or `brew cask install emacs-mac` if you prefer cask binaries).

Comment: Also, you probably should break this question into (at least) 4 distinct questions...

Comment: Regarding item 1: could be something related to this https://github.com/milkypostman/powerline/issues/120

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Ideally, each post should contain a single, discrete question, rather than a list of them.  Could you please edit your post to make it a single question?  It is okay to do multiple posts for multiple questions.  (Ideally, though, you could point to issues in the [spaceline documentation](https://github.com/TheBB/spaceline) that you need help with.)

Comment: The Mod next to Git:master means the file is modified.